# How to replicate class based components async setState method with react-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the state for every element of the array. But after execution of the function, only the last array element is there in the state?

In class based component, we use callback method with the setstate function to perform any action with the updated state. How to do this in hook?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";


export default function App() {
 const [state, setState] = useState([]);

const add = ({name, value}) => {
  setState( [...state, {name, value}]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('update')
}, [state])

const handleClick = () => {
const array = [{
  name: 'Sam',
  value: '23'
},{
  name: 'Ram',
  value: '24'
},{
  name: 'Pam',
  value: '25'
}]
for(const a of array){
  console.log({a})
  add(a);
  }
}
return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous. By repeatedly doing

```
setState( [...state, {name, value}]);
```

you're using the original `state` several times, not the new one.

Ideally, don't call `setState` repeatedly without allowing your component to rerender in between, do something like this instead:

```
const addAll = (entries) => {
  setState([...state, ...entries]);
};

addAll(array);
```

But if you need to call your state setter repeatedly, use the callback form so that you're always using the then-current state, not stale state:

```
setState(currentState => [...currentState, {name, value}]);
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> `setState(currentState => ({...currentState, [name]: value}))` But for object its not working

It does, that code looks exactly right, assuming you're trying to set the property whose name is in `name` to `value`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    });
    
    const updateProperty = (name, value) => {
        setState(currentState => ({...currentState, [name]: value}));
    };
    
    const addA = () => {
        updateProperty("a", state.a + 1);
    };
    
    const addB = () => {
        updateProperty("b", state.b + 1);
    };
    
    const addC = () => {
        updateProperty("c", (state.c || 0) + 1);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>a = {state.a}, b = {state.b}, c = {state.c}</div>
            <input type="button" value="Inc A" onClick={addA} />
            <input type="button" value="Inc B" onClick={addB} />
            <input type="button" value="Create/Inc C" onClick={addC} />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

That isn't how I'd recommend doing that, though. With hooks, it's best to keep your state items discrete:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(1);
    const [b, setB] = useState(2);
    const [c, setC] = useState(undefined);
    
    const addA = () => {
        setA(a => a + 1);
    };
    
    const addB = () => {
        setB(b => b + 1);
    };
    
    const addC = () => {
        setC(c => (c || 0) + 1);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>a = {a}, b = {b}, c = {c}</div>
            <input type="button" value="Inc A" onClick={addA} />
            <input type="button" value="Inc B" onClick={addB} />
            <input type="button" value="Create/Inc C" onClick={addC} />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: setState(currentState => ({...currentState, [name]: value}))
But for object its not working . @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @SujoySaha - That works just fine, I've added an example to the end of the answer. That code looks exacty right if you're updating the property whose name is in `name` to match the value `value`.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831109/useeffect-is-not-running-for-every-change-in-dependency-array) @TJCrowder please refer this question