# useEffect is not running for every change in dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I update an expense, it doesn't trigger the useEffect to store the the data in local storage.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hodgkin-bu1oc)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ExpenseContext = React.createContext();

const ExpenseState = (props) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState(
      () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expenses')) || []
);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('didUpdate', state)
    state.length !== 0 && localStorage.setItem('expenses', JSON.stringify(state));
}, [state]) 

function addExpense({id, name, category, value, note, date}){
    const expense = state.find(exp => exp.id === id);
    if(!expense){
        setState(state => ([...state, {id, name, category, value, note, date}]))
    }else{
        const updatedExpense = state.map(exp => {
                if(exp.id === expense.id){
                    return {
                        ...exp,
                        ...{id, name, category, value, note, date}
                    }
                }else{
                    return exp
                }
            })

        setState(updatedExpense)
    }
    console.log(state)
}



return (
    <ExpenseContext.Provider
        value={{
            expenses: state,
            addExpense: addExpense,
        }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </ExpenseContext.Provider>
)
}
```

I am calling the addExpense for every elements of the array. Assume we have 4 expenses stored in storage. Now we have updated one expense and then running the below code.

```
for(const expense of expenses){
        expenseContext.addExpense(expense);
    }
```

Now the use effect only get triggered for the last element and the expense also not getting updated in context.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Sure, [it's documented](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) - on the very page that is linked - it's for lazy initialization of state

Comment: Thanks @mfeineis! The `|| []` is still unnecessary, though, right? `useState` never returns a falsy value.

Comment: No, that's also fine, that seems to be the fallback for the initial case when no data is found via `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("expenses"))`. I put the code into a codesandbox, seems to work just fine, although it'd be better to `useCallback` the callbacks, obviously https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-cherry-06to9

Comment: @mfeineis - But `useState` returns a `[state, setter]` array, so it doesn't matter if `state` is falsy, the array never will be. Yes, it'll *work*, because `|| []` never gets involved so it doesn't matter, but... (You have to look closely -- perhaps you already have -- but that line is `= useState(/*function*/) || [];`)

Comment: It's not, I'll just copy it in and delete some whitespace :-) `const [state, setState] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expenses')) || []);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder mfeineis added the codesandbox link in question

Comment: @SujoySaha - Which would be great, but as I said on your last question, questions must be self-contained. Again, please use the **on-site** resources available to you as described above.

Comment: @mfeineis Any help?

Comment: Not really, as I said the code is working inside codesandbox, so it's probably your usage of the components that's causing the issue and there I can only speculate since you didn't provide that part of the code

Comment: @mfeineis please check the codesandbox now. I have updated the code. The expense is not getting updated

Answer (score 0):

You code is working, I'm not sure if you just **missed** some stuff?

**1.** `export default ExpenseState` is missing?

**2.** **Wrap** your App with `ExpenseState` context

Assuming you have a default **CRA** setup:

```js
// index.js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import ExpenseState from "./AppContext" // or where your Context

import App from "./App"

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDOM.render(
  <ExpenseState>
    <App />
  </ExpenseState>,
  rootElement
)
```

And your **App.js**

```js
// App.js
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { ExpenseContext } from "./AppContext"

export default () => {
  const { expenses, addExpense } = useContext(ExpenseContext)

  const handleExpense = () => {
    addExpense({
      id: 1, // Change ID to add another object
      name: "some name",
      category: "some category", // keep the id and change some values for update
      value: "some value",
      note: "some note",
      date: "some date"
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleExpense}>Add Expenses</button>
      <pre>
        <code>{JSON.stringify(expenses, null, 2)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Working [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-sandbox-form-weny6) example.

Comment: add also working for me. I am having issue with the update. Please check the codesandbox(https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hodgkin-bu1oc)

Comment: Base on the code logic, you can't update unless the `id` is different and your `setCounter` state always produce a new `id` so update will not work.

Comment: please check the link now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `useState` is working differently than you think it does. Inside the consumer you're calling `api.addExpense(...)` three times in a row synchronously with the expectation that calling `setState` will update `state` in-place - it doesn't, the state is only updated on the next render call and not at line 40 as your `console.log` there suggests you're expecting it to.

So instead of the three complete state updates you're expecting (one for each `expense`) you only get the state from the last update for `{id: "d6109eb5-9d7b-4cd3-8daa-ee485b08361b", name: "book", category: "personal care", value: 200}`, which has no changes and is still based on the *original state* not one where the first item's value has been set to 800.

I'd suggest modifying your `ExpenseState` api to take an array of expenses so it can handle multiple internal updates appropriately.

```js
  function addOrUpdateExpense(state, { id, name, category, value }) {
    const expense = state.find(exp => exp.id === id);
    if (!expense) {
      return [...state, { id, name, category, value }];
    } else {
      const updatedExpense = state.map(exp => {
        if (exp.id === expense.id) {
          return {
            ...exp,
            ...{ id, name, category, value }
          };
        } else {
          return exp;
        }
      });

      return updatedExpense;
    }
  }

  function addExpenses(expenses) {
    let newState = [...state];
    for (const expense of expenses) {
      newState = addOrUpdateExpense(newState, expense);
    }
    setState(newState);
  }

  // ...usage

  function doIt() {
    api.addExpenses(expenses);
  }
```

This is a common misconception, just remember that the next state is only available asynchronously in the next render phase, treat state from `useState` as immutable within a render pass.